# how to mixin gem-modules in ruby-on-rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mixins, one-time-password

I am building a gem in which i have a module `OtpGenerator`. inside this module i have methods like `generate_otp`, `verify_otp` etc. This is just a begining for me and its very simple gem only to generate and verify and save and send, nothing else. Now anyone who uses this gem will have to include this module in their model. for e.g. there is a `user` model. now what i want is first i will create a instance

`user = User.new(params[:user])`

now i need to do the operation `user.generate_otp`, this will assign otp related things in the activerecord instance.

after that `user.save`, which is also fine.

But i also want a function `generate_otp!`, which will do all task like generates otp, than save it and sends it. My problem is that i am not getting how to achieve this functionality.

Note: I am very new to ruby. and really getting confused with mixins.

here is my code for `otp.rb` file

```
require 'securerandom'

module OtpGenerator
  def generate_otp
    #do something here
  end

  def verify_otp(otp)
    #do something here
  end

  def regenerate_otp
    #do something here
  end

  def matches?(generated, otp)
    #do something here
  end

  def expired?(otp_expiry_time)
    #do something here
  end
end
```

This code is still in development, i just want to know that how to implement `generate_otp!` function, which will do all three operation,i.e,
(1) generates otp(user.generate_otp)
(2) saves otp(user.save)
(3) sends otp (i have created the send function, so thats not a problem.)

Comment: as you mentioned the generate_otp! should be as simple as you've described it! add the three methods in the sequence they are to be executed. One problem I could actually see to this is that even the OTP generated doesn't seem to be stored anywhere, which is a bit of problem because I'm sure the verify would need a reference to that

Comment: `generate_otp!` method is in my gem's module which will be included to model. now when `user.generate_otp!` is called i am not sure how will i implement `user.save` in my module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a mixin in your model, then your model should also have access to it. Here is what I mean:

```
class User
  include OtpGenerator
end

module OtpGenerator
...
  def generate_otp!
    generate_otp
    save
    send_generated_otp
  end
end
```

When you call `User.find(45).generate_otp!`

That would work because of the way inheritances work in Ruby. Once the module is included within a class, it inherits all the methods of the module and the module has access to the context of the included class.

Hope that answers your question

Comment: thanks @oreoluwa for the reply, but as i am new to ruby i am still learning about mixins, so as you speicified, will it mean that when i call `user.generate_otp!`, it will call all three methods is order, i.e, `user.generate_otp`, `user.save` and than my send function. also note that save function is not implemented by me, it is the inbuilt function to save details in database.

Comment: because as i have specified app developer will create a new instance variable `user` which gets all parameters,i.e., `user = User.new(params[:user])`. now `user.save` will save details in db. well you seem an experienced guy you know it better than me.

Comment: Yes, `save` is ActiveRecord. But because you'd be including the gem in the scope of an ActiveRecord instance, you'd be able to call the save method. I'd say you should try it out though